# Graph theory and combinatorics

Tags: graph-theory

Show that there is no graph $G$ with $V (G) = 12$ and $E(G) = 28$ in
which each vertex is of degree either $3$ or $4$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: by the handshaking lemma, we have
$$
\sum_{v\in V}d(v)=2E(G)
$$
Suppose each vertex has degree $4$.  Then this becomes
$$
\sum_{v\in V}4=12\times 4=48=2E(G)
$$
On the other hand, if $E(G) = 28$, then $2E(G) = 56$.
What can we conclude?

In general then, we can say that if each vertex is of degree $3$ or $4$, then
$$
\sum_{v\in V}d(v)\leq 12\times 4=48
$$
How does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If $v_3$ is the number of vertices of degree $3$, $v_4$ the number of degree $4$, and $e$ th enumber of edges, then by counting vertex-edge incidences, we get
$$ 3v_3+4v_4=2e.$$
With $v_3+v_4=12$, this implies
$$36\le (3(v_3+v_4)+4_v=2e=4(v_3+v_4)-v_3\le 48$$